Something went wrong message after fresh install of Fedora 40
I've been struggling with this for days now, every resource I came acrooss takls about upgrade and not fresh install.
I want to install Fedora 40 Workstation on a completely wiped SSD from USB and after first boot with no user yet created or anything, it comes to a GNOME for a few seconds and then a problem message: "Oh, no, something went wrong and system can't recover" I have AMD Ryzen 5 system with NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1650 graphics only (no integrated). I installed Fedora with ¨nomodeset¨ option, as I heard that other modes in installer are not supported.
I encountered the same problem with Fedora 39. After this error I can only go in the console with CTRL+ALT+Fx but cannot do much there as no user is yet created.
What to do here?
